# PHP Paypal IPN Error

Tags: php

I have a code that is sending the buyer to paypal, when he pays it's going to the listener file.

```
<?php namespace Listener;

 require('PaypalIPN.php');

 mail("XXX", "Test IPN 1", "Paypal IPN!");

 use PaypalIPN;

 $ipn = new PaypalIPN();

 $verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
 if ($verified)
 {
   mail("XXX", "Test IPN", "Paypal IPN!");
   if($_POST["payment_status"] == "Completed" || $_POST["payment_status"] == "Pending")
   {

   }
 }
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

It is sending the first mail but not the second one.

It doesn't do any code after the `if()` of the verified.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Where should I get them?

Comment: In your error logs. You can also enable [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in your PHP script.

Comment: No errors in my logs.

Comment: Then is `$verified` TRUE?

Comment: I just checked and nothing happend after the `$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();`

Comment: So what is the value of `$verified`? Try adding a check/printing something when `$verified` is FALSE.

Comment: @JustBaron I tried to put after the line of the `$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();` a mail send and it is not working.

Comment: Anyone?? Please I really need help.

Comment: Is there any `$_POST` data for the `verifyIPN()` function, is this `sandbox`, and do you have `cURL` enabled?

Comment: I don't know if there is any `$_POST` data because it stops the code right after the `$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();`, I'm not using sandbox and cURL is enabled.

Comment: Have you tested this in a sandbox first?

Comment: No, How can I test it in sandbox?

Comment: [PayPal IPN samples](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php) & [Example usage](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage.php)

Comment: After I've done this and I made a sandbox account, what should I do ?

Comment: Follow the PayPal guidelines, I can't hold your hand through every problem you may encounter. SO is a question and answer forum...not a tutorial site. The examples provided in the links I gave you should be enough.

Comment: But still I didn't recive ANY solution for this issue, and I'm stuck again where I was.

Comment: That's because this is very hard for us to replicate. I have a feeling that you need to configure your PayPal sandbox correctly. Your script would only "stop working" if you have an error. Take a look at the [PayPal IPN class](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php) and chase the problem down.